# If I want to get all Britney Spears twitter followers using the rest api, how much time would it take?

Tags: twitter, twitter-oauth

Britney Spears has hitherto 43.1M followers, if a want a list of all of the followers how much time would it take?

I've calculated about 57 hours (720 request/hour times 100 followers, using api `users/lookup`, is this correct?

If the above is correct is there a way to minimize the time?

I was thinking in using multiples `auth token` but I don't know if I can share `twitter cursors` between several request.

I mean, make the first request using one token, then get the cursor for the next page but make the second request with another token. Is this viable?

Comment: Why `users/lookup`? Do you know already the followers and you want to get info from them? If you don't know the followers you need to use `followers/id` which is much slower (300K followers an hour)... Anyway your idea of using different tokens is good. I would do the 15 requests for the window first, then change token, 15 requests more, etc. Hope it helps.

Comment: Yeah I would use first `followers/id` but that endpoint is faster so the slower is `users/lookup` at 7200 per hour. But the real question is: is the cursor stable, if I get a cursor using one token and use that cursor with another token would i get the same data as If I were suing the the cursor with only one token?

Comment: Ah ok, now I understand about `users/lookup`, sorry. As for the cursor, it is only an id, so I would say that your idea is very good and I think it should work, but I haven't tried it myself. (If I had, I would post an answer).